# Angular div not changing text when updating $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm have a button that will change the underlying `$scope` and it can show it changes but the text in the mapped/bound `div` doesn't change

to specify my desired result is when I click the button with the text `button` it should change the text of `<div id="text">` how ever it doesn't so I'm not sure what I'm doing incorrectly

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('myCtrl', function($scope){
 $scope.data =
   {"person": 
     {"id": 3,
      "text": "this is the text value"
      }
  };
    
});

setTimeout(function(){
var elem = document.getElementById('ex');
elem.addEventListener('click',
function(){
 $scope = angular.element(document.getElementById('text')).scope();
  $scope.data.person.text = "this is new text";
},false);

elem = document.getElementById('log');
elem.addEventListener('click', function(){
console.log(angular.element(document.getElementById('text')).scope().data.person.text);
},false)

//alert('load');
},500);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div id="id" ng-model="data.person.id">{{data.person.id}}</div>
  <div id="text" ng-model="data.person.text">{{data.person.text}}</div>
</div>

<button id="ex">
button
</button>

<button id="log">
log
</button>
```

Comment: you can not bind model to `div`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since you are using `setTimeout` function you need to manually start the `$digest` cycle. use `$scope.$apply()` after the text change. It will start the cycle and bind the values to view

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('myCtrl', function($scope){
 $scope.data =
   {"person": 
     {"id": 3,
      "text": "this is the text value"
      }
  };
    
});

setTimeout(function(){
var elem = document.getElementById('ex');
elem.addEventListener('click',
function(){
 $scope = angular.element(document.getElementById('text')).scope();
  $scope.data.person.text = "this is new text";
  $scope.$apply()
},false);

elem = document.getElementById('log');
elem.addEventListener('click', function(){
console.log(angular.element(document.getElementById('text')).scope().data.person.text);
},false)

//alert('load');
},500);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div id="id" ng-model="data.person.id">{{data.person.id}}</div>
  <div id="text" ng-model="data.person.text">{{data.person.text}}</div>
</div>

<button id="ex">
button
</button>

<button id="log">
log
</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

There are Angular directives to do this, use [ngClick](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick) like that :

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('myCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.data = {"person": {"id": 3, "text": "this is the text value"}};
    
    $scope.changeTextValue = function(){
      $scope.data.person.text = "this is new text";
    }
    
    $scope.log = function(){
      console.log($scope.data.person.text);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div>{{data.person.id}}</div>
  <div>{{data.person.text}}</div>
  <button ng-click="changeTextValue()">
    button
  </button>

  <button ng-click="log()">
    log
  </button>
</div>
```

Also [ngModel](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) is only used for an `input`, a `select` or a `textarea`. Using `{{data.person.id}}` is sufficient to get `data.person.id` value (check this page for more informations on [interpolation and data binding](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/interpolation))

Comment: You should omit the `ng-model` from the div elements and explain why they are not correct

Comment: Thank you for explaining `ng-model`

Answer (score 1):

AngularJs one of main advantage is 2 way binding and help user to avoid DOM access and manipulation through code (Avoid using `document.getElementById())`.

You have written event handler code outside the controller, which is not in AngularJs scope. All your view's behaviour can go inside the controller and then you can access the scope data with `$scope` directly. attach the event handler to the event attribute `ng-click` (for click event) in your button. Bind the required data to div with one way binding like `{{data}}`. ng-model is not required here as you are not editing it through UI.